# uft-file-system-execution task in azure devops not executing complete testscripts provided in the mtb file

Tags: automation, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, uft14

I have provided around 20 Testscripts in mtb file, It executes only the first 8 testscripts and skips rest of them. It is getting struck after executing 8 scripts.
Can anyone help me with this, I am struck from past 2 to 3 days on this issue?

Comment: Welcome on SO. In order to get a help please show us logs?

Comment: When you execute the mtb file on your local machine, will it run all scripts?  In addition to task log, you can also share mtb file content. Then we can give you better help.